# Convolution proof (symmetric)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, convolution

I want to show, that for some functions $ f,g \in L^1(\mathbb{R^n})$ hold:
$$f*g=g*f$$

My proof so far:

$ f*g= \int_{\mathbb{R^n}} f(x-y)f(y) dy$
Substitution: $\phi(y) =x-y$
This leads to:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R^n}} f(\phi(y)) g(y) | Det(D \phi(y)| = \int_{\mathbb{R^n}} f(\phi(y)) g(y) (-1)^n dy$$
How can I go on from there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Jacobian is $1$, not $(-1)^{n}$. (You forgot the absolute value). So $\int f(x-y)g(y)dy=\int f(y)g(x-y)dy$ and $(f*g)(x)=(g*f)(x)$.

Comment: I see:) But then I have $ \int_{\mathbb{R^n}} f(\phi(y)) g(y) dy$ How do you get to $ \int f(y)g(x-y)$ ?

Comment: $\int f(\phi(y))g(y)dy=\int f(z)g(\phi^{-1}(z))dz$ Note that $x-y=z$ is same as $x-z=y$. hence $\phi^{-1}=\phi$ so we get $\int f(z)g(\phi (z))dz$. Now change the 'dummy' variable $z$ to $y$.

Comment: Sorry I do not unterstand why $ x-y=z$ and $x-z=y$ should be the same. Both are linear transformations.

Comment: $x-y=z$ means $x=y+z$. $x-z=y$ also means $x=y+z$.

Comment: Thank you for your help:)